# Located in Asia

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus

The answer to this little puzzle consists of two words.

---

[image]

Comment: The first thing I thought of when I saw the word "Asia" and then a lump that looked like a rot13(zbhagnva)  was rot13(Zbhag Rirerfg)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is:

> **MOUNT EVEREST**!

To find this, first identify the six images placed beneath the 'mountain' shape. Each of these...

> ...contributes **two letters** to the answer. They are (row by row):
>
>  A logo for the **UN**;
>  The prefix **RE**, as in 'RETURN' (for example);
>
>  A picture of **ST.** John the Baptist;
>  A picture of Eve in the Garden of Eden, from whose name we extract the second and third letters: **VE**;
>
>  A *reversed* movie poster for the film E.T., providing us with **TE**;
>  A *reversed* image of an 'Om' symbol, giving **MO**.

We can then:

> rearrange these two-letter chunks in the order **MO**, **UN**, **TE**, **VE**, **RE**, **ST** and concatenate them to give the name of a mountain in Asia (indicated by the mountainous shape and the title): **MOUNT EVEREST**!
>
>  Being the tallest mountain in the world, this 'little' puzzle is heavily laden with irony - paha!

Comment: Correct :) Well done!